# Linux how to force quit the process by root

Tags: linux, centos

I have run the command to backup 7 accounts and then i want to quit that command while its running.
How can i quit from command line

I want that it should quit backing up all accounts not just current account and then i have to press again untill all accounts open

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+C will kill the command if you ran it in the foreground from the same shell.

`kill -9` will destroy everything in its path if you are killing it from a different environment, or you ran the command in the background.

Comment: i tried ctrl c but it then come to shell but processing is still going on

Comment: Please don't do `kill -9` when it's not necessary. http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/ and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...

Answer (score 0):

Use ps aux command to determine process which runs next backup and kill it, for example with kill -9.

Comment: Please don't do `kill -9` when it's not necessary. http://sial.org/howto/shell/kill-9/ and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps aux` to determine the processid. Then kill it with `kill -15 1234`(where 1234 is the processid)